# Zoom out whole website using css

Tags: css, responsive-design

i used this css code to zoom out my divs for better view in smaller screens.

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
-webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
```

its output in firefox and IE browser is ok but no result in chrome.
what should i do?

Comment: It should be `zoom: 0.8` for webkit.

Comment: `divs for better view in smaller screens` I'd it's better to use relative units to size the elements. Also `@media`-queries would help.

Comment: thanks all,zoom: 0.8 dose not work in latest chrome version i use , i used this code under media query

Comment: I think the latest Chrome does not require prefixes.